# How to limit boost::combine to the minimum of two ranges

Tags: c++, boost

Finding the following as the source of a segfault just cost me about 4h of work:

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main(int, const char*[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::list<char> l;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        l.push_back(static_cast<char>(i) + 'a');
    }

    v.push_back(5);

    int ti;
    char tc;
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(ti, tc), boost::combine(v, l))
    {
        std::cout << '(' << ti << ',' << tc << ')' << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you execute this example, you will note that combine happily iterates as long as the longer range has values. I do not see this in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html).

Is there a way to limit the iteration to the shorter of the two ranges?

Comment: You could [slice](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html) the containers, but only if both of them are random-access. To be honest, I'd rather use iterators directly at this point.

Comment: I guess on some level this makes sense because at no point is the internal "current" iterator tuple equal to the "end" iterator tuple. That this gives rise to the kind of bug shown here should be made very clear in the documentation though, not just by showing [some examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) that use equal-length ranges...